# Turn off ram releasing in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, ram

Inside of iOS is there any way to turn off the automatic RAM cleaning(app closing) when phone is sleeping? (on locked screen)
I have found this option in my android device and this is very essential for the app I am budiling to do the same on iPhone but I cant find this option anywhere.
In android you can find this option in:

```
settings>application options>control panel>clean the RAM>set to never
```

Comment: No, iOS can terminate your app at any time once it is suspended.  Available background execution modes are described in the *iOS Application Programming Guide*. If you don't need to execute in the background, but merely give the appearance that the app wasn't terminated when it is opened, then you should look into state restoration.

Comment: so could you tell me what can be the possible reason that my app is not being terminted at all on other iPhone but on my iPhone it is being terminated after about 1 minute?

Comment: Your phone have other app running that it needs more RAM, so it will kill other app to make space, thats all